# Can I use 1/4 inch cork to equalize floors before installing laminate flooring?

Tags: flooring, laminate, linoleum

We are planning on installing laminate.  We would like to install over top of the lino but there's a 1/4 inch difference between the kitchen and the living room flooring.

I was wondering if using [1/4 inch cork such as this product](http://www.homedepot.ca/product/200-sqfeet-50feet-x-4feet-x-1-4-inch-cork-underlayment/804719?eid=PS_GO_140203__ALL_PLA-804719&pid=804719&kpid=804719&gclid=CJbe7LG_qMECFVBffgodyCoAQA#BVRRWidgetID) to equalize the floor heights and then laying a foam underlay overtop of everything would be a good option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way I would use a cork underlayment to make the floors equal.  Cork has too many expanding properties.  I don't even think you could get the cork to "sit" under a thin laminate.  Also cork will feel softer than most other forms of underlayment.  To the point where your floors will feel different.

I would use plywood or what is under higher floor (probably plywood).

Comment: It is plywood under the lino.  That's what I was thinking too...that the cork might depress after being used for a while.  It's not a super thin laminate.  10mm

Comment: Worse is if the cork get a little wet/humid it will expand.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm glad I asked.  We'll go ahead with the plywood.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with your answer (lord knows putting a floor on top of what is basically a giant sponge sounds like a bad idea) but in the link provided in the question it does specifically say its made to go under laminate flooring. I guess if your floor gets wet enough to soak down into the cork the laminate would be ruined anyway...?

Comment: @paperstreet - I would not have an issue putting the cork down everywhere on a floor that could never have water issues (not a basement).  The problem isn't the cork, it is that the cork is different than the plywood.  But as you mention it is a sponge and there are some quality underlayments that are durable, soft, and handle water better than cork.